# Not able to call a function onfocus event in php

Tags: php, javascript

I am not able to call a functions on onfocus and onblur events, both perfectly working in html but not in php here is code in php:

```
echo "<input value='Enter Name' onfocus= 'areaOnFocus(text1, 'Enter Name')' onblur='areaOnBlur(text1, 'Enter Name')' type='text' name='text1' id='text1'>";
```

both functions are called in script tag. I am sure that call to function is not made in this case as I am alerting in script tag , but nothing happen.

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Well you're messing up with quotes there. I think you're using single quotes everywhere to avoid problems with the double quotes enclosing the string, but then you have this problem:

```
onfocus= 'areaOnFocus(text1, 'Enter Name')'
```

the single quote starts the string at `areaOnFocus` and ends it *before* `Enter name`.

You can either play with double quotes spamming like this:

```
echo "<input value=\"Enter Name\" onfocus=\"areaOnFocus(text1, 'Enter Name')\" onblur=\"areaOnBlur(text1, 'Enter Name')\" type=\"text\" name=\"text1\" id=\"text1\">";
```

or - better - put the HTML code **outside** PHP blocks.

Comment: Did that, but no luck, strange is that when i run this much code only in separate sample.php file it works.

Comment: You also said that to put html code outside php block, but how can i place it where it suppose to be

Comment: Are you sure the final HTML generated is correct? Is the `areaOnFocus` function defined? Can you check on a javascript console for errors?

Comment: ok this is the whole code: code for js: function areaOnFocus(element, inputText)
    {
        //alert(inputText);
        //alert (element);
         if(element.value == inputText)
         {
    
              element.value='';
    
         }
    
    }
    
    function areaOnBlur(element, inputText)
    {
        //alert(inputText);
        //alert (element);
         if(element.value=='')
         {
    
              element.value = inputText;
    
         }
    
    }
 and this one for in php:

Comment: contd: echo "<input value=\"Enter Name\" onfocus=\"areaOnFocus(text1, 'Enter Name')\" onblur=\"areaOnBlur(text1, 'Enter Name')\" type=\"text\" name=\"text1\" id=\"text1\">";